# Is there a closed expression for the limit of the following function?

Tags: calculus

It seems to me that the incomplete Beta function is related here, but I am interested in two things, first in the limit of the following function when $\beta \to \infty$:
\begin{equation}
f_{\alpha,\beta}(x)=\displaystyle\frac{\Gamma(\beta +1)}{\Gamma(\alpha +\beta +2)}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\displaystyle\frac{\Gamma(\alpha +\beta +j +2)}{\Gamma(\beta+j +2)}x^j.
\end{equation}

Where $\alpha, \beta\in \mathbb{R}$, such that $\alpha>-1$ and $x\in [0,1)$. Function $f$ is analytic in $[0, 1)$. Second, ¿is there any function by which we can express $f_{\alpha, \beta}$?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: For all $z$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{\Gamma(n+z)}{\Gamma(n)n^z}}=1$ by e.g. the Euler product.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\displaystyle\frac{\Gamma(\alpha +\beta +j +2)}{\Gamma(\beta+j +2)}x^j=\frac{\Gamma (\alpha +\beta +2) }{\Gamma
   (\beta +2)}\,\, _2F_1(1,\alpha +\beta +2;\beta +2;x)$$
$$f_{\alpha,\beta}(x)=\frac 1{\beta +1 }\,\, _2F_1(1,\alpha +\beta +2;\beta +2;x)$$ If $(\alpha,\beta)$ are positive integers
$$\, _2F_1(1,\alpha +\beta +2;\beta +2;x)=\frac {P_{\alpha }(x)}{(1-x)^{\alpha+1} }$$ where $P_{\alpha }(x)$ is a complete polynomial of degree $\alpha$ in $x$